# Is the improper integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sin (4x) dx$ convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

Is the improper integral $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sin (4x) dx$ convergent?
$\bf{Try:} $

$\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sin (4x) dx=\displaystyle \int_{-\infty} ^{0} \sin (4x) dx +\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty} \sin (4x) dx $
Now let $\phi(t) =\displaystyle \int_{0}^{t}\sin (4x)dx \implies \phi(t) =\frac 14 - \frac{\cos 4t}4$
Now $\displaystyle \lim_{t\to \infty} \phi(t) =\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac 14 - \frac{\cos 4t}4\right) $
This limit does not exist because $\cos$ is oscillating. Hence the improper integral is divergent.

But if we consider $\phi(t) =\displaystyle \int_{-t}^{t} \sin (4x)dx =0$ since $\sin$  is odd function. Here $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} \phi(t) =0\implies \text{the improper integral is convergent} $.
I'm confused which one to consider the first one or the second one? Please help me understand. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Everything that you've written is mathematically correct, except perhaps the most important part. What **exactly** are you using as the definition of what it means for this improper integral to converge?

Comment: You should look up the concept of the Cauchy Principal Value of an integral.

Comment: Check out my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3131183/is-the-property-int-aafxdx-int-aaf-xdx-still-applicable-when).

Comment: @TheoBendit Thanks for your work (+1).So as I understand from your answer that the improper integral I have put here is divergent.

Comment: @Math-Learner Correct.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sin x \, \mathrm{dx}$ divergent or convergent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/725025/is-int-infty-infty-sin-x-mathrmdx-divergent-or-convergent)

Comment: @TheoBendit No that question is almost same but not lights the specific issue I wanted to be addressed.

Comment: Hint:

this two limits are in general different

$$
\lim_{(a,b)\rightarrow(-\infty,\infty)}\int^b_a f(x)\,dx
$$
which is equivalent to 
$$
\lim_{a\rightarrow-\infty}\int^{x_0}_a f(x)\,dx +\lim_{b\rightarrow\infty}\int^b_{x_0}f(x)\,dx,
$$
and
$$
\lim_{b\rightarrow\infty}\int^b_{-b} f(x)\,dx
$$